# Getting the right response but it still getting errors

Tags: php, android, android-asynctask

I got the right response but still getting errors and its strange.

Where i press the button to go to next activity:

```
private void setupClickEvent() {
        signIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                userName = username.getText().toString();
                userPass = password.getText().toString();

                if (!userName.isEmpty() || !userPass.isEmpty()) {
                    accessWebService();
                    Log.e("after execute: ", String.valueOf(letLogin));
                    if (letLogin) {
                        session.createLoginSession(userName, "waiterx@gmail.com");
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), UserProfile.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right);
                        getActivity().finish();
                    } else {
                        Snackbar.with(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).text(getString(R.string.uname_or_password_not_found)).color(Color.parseColor("#3399FF")).show(getActivity());
                    }
                }

            }
        });
    }

    private void accessWebService() {
        task = new MyInsertDataTask();
        task.execute(new String[]{URL});
    }
```

UPDATED JAVA:

```
private class MyInsertDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            pDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
            pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            pDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.dialog_rate_data_submit));
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", userName));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", userPass));
            try
            {
                httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                httpPost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                httpEntity = response.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }
                Log.e("HTTP response: ", result.toString());

                if (result != null){
                    data = new JSONObject(result.toString());
                    isRegistered = data.getBoolean("res");}
                Log.e("isRegistered: ", String.valueOf(isRegistered));

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
            }
            return isRegistered;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

And still does not logging me in!!!!

The logcat output:

```
09-23 04:36:48.627  22163-22163/com.order.app.order E/after execute:﹕ false
09-23 04:36:48.659  22163-22182/com.order.app.order W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
09-23 04:36:48.659  22163-22182/com.order.app.order W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xabc9aa60, error=EGL_SUCCESS
09-23 04:36:51.240  22163-22188/com.order.app.order E/HTTP response:﹕ {"res":true}
09-23 04:36:51.240  22163-22188/com.order.app.order E/isRegistered:﹕ true
09-23 04:36:53.777  22163-22163/com.order.app.order E/after execute:﹕ true
09-23 04:36:53.812  22163-22182/com.order.app.order W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
09-23 04:36:53.812  22163-22182/com.order.app.order W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa1d555c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
09-23 04:36:53.815  22163-22185/com.order.app.order E/HTTP response:﹕ {"res":true}
09-23 04:36:53.815  22163-22185/com.order.app.order E/isRegistered:﹕ true
```

Since the responce is true and i give `isRegistered` the value from the data object why is it still troubles me? The First time i click the button the letLogin variable is false and the Second time is true. How is this possible? Anyone would be able to help me appreciate it!!!

Comment: There is something wrong with accesswebservice Method. doInBackground returns isRegistered true and after the task.execute the isRegistered gets false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found it at last why it needed 2 times to press the button. 1 to execute and 1 to confirm for correct data.

The code:

```
private class MyInsertDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            pDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
            pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            pDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.dialog_rate_data_submit));
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }


        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", userName));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", userPass));
            try {
                httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                httpPost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                httpEntity = response.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }
                Log.e("HTTP response: ", result.toString());

                if (result != null) {
                    data = new JSONObject(result.toString());
                    isRegistered = data.getBoolean("res");
                }
                Log.e("isRegistered: ", String.valueOf(isRegistered));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
            }
            return isRegistered;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if (aVoid) {
                session.createLoginSession(userName, "waiterx@gmail.com");
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), UserProfile.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right);
                getActivity().finish();
            }else {
                Snackbar.with(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).text(getString(R.string.uname_or_password_not_found)).color(Color.parseColor("#3399FF")).show(getActivity());
            }
        }
    }
```

And the execution:

```
private void setupClickEvent() {
        signIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                userName = username.getText().toString();
                userPass = password.getText().toString();
                if (!userName.isEmpty() || !userPass.isEmpty()) {
                    accessWebService();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    private void accessWebService() {
        task = new MyInsertDataTask();
        task.execute(new String[]{URL});
    }
```

Works like a charm. Thank you all for your time!!!

Answer (score 0):

You just convert json array to object, the parse it. Instead of

```
  if (result != null){
                    data = new JSONObject(result);
                    if (data != null){
                        isRegistered = data.getBoolean("res");
              } }
```

Use this code

```
if (result != null){
jArray = new JSONArray(result.toString());
JSONObject data = jArray.getJSONObject(0); //first data, if multiple data, use loop
isRegistered = data.getBoolean("res");}
```

In case you have multiple data, use loop inside.

Comment: check the logcat output isRegistered gives me true and still does not log me in

Comment: i want to know if there is something wrong with the code of accesswebservice. i have initialised isRegistered as false and in doInBackground it gets true and then in acesswebservice method it gets false again. why is that?

Comment: i mean that in accessWebService method isRegistered is still false...where does doInBackground returns the Boolean?

Comment: That means your function is not waiting for asynctask to complete.. It is already meant inside async task.. So confirm that by putting some log info inside accessWebService() function. @KostasDrakonakis

Comment: well after that i execute the async task i check for the value of the boolean

Answer (score 0):

I think you just forgot a toString when creating your JsonObject.

Try to use this:

```
data = new JSONObject(result.toString);
```

Instead of:

```
data = new JSONObject(result);
```

Anyway try a step by step debugging